# Jquery can't reset input type where id match inside of the form

Tags: jquery

I have a reset button use Jquery, I only want to reset where id=b, however it is not working when I place inside of `<form>` It reset everything inside of the form

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".b").val("");
  });
});
</script>


<form action="c.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="t1" class="a">
    <input type="text" name="t2" class="b">
    <input type="text" name="t3" class="b">

    <button>Reset</button>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `id=from2` is it typo or what? and you don't have form id in the markup.

Comment: You have two inputs with the same ID, that's not valid. Is that the way the real code is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of submitting the form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        $("#form2").val("");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

See my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/py4RF/)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to do it like this:

```
<form action="c.php" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="t1">
  <input type="text" name="t2" class="clear-on-reset">
  <input type="text" name="t3" class="clear-on-reset">

  <input id="reset" type="button" value="Reset" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You set class on fields which you want to clear on reset, for example *clear-on-reset*
You set custom id for reset button, in my case *reset*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#reset").click(function(){
    $(".clear-on-reset").val("");
  });
});
```

This way you don`t have to prevent default action on button click.
Problems will occur if you will add another button on form, because it will trigger the same 'reset' function and prevent default.

Link to fiddle: [click](http://jsfiddle.net/aZftc/2/)